# What is the name of the small red counter shown over some icon on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icons

I'm looking for the name of the small red counter in the picture below. Thanks !

[image: Small red counter]

Comment: Curious : 2 downvotes. Some people think that we're all working on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 92;
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. Icon badge will be shorter in my mails than "the small red counter" :) Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It is called **BadgeNumber**
And you can set it also this way

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: Thank, but I'm not developing on iOS at all :) Cheers.

Comment: @SylvainRodrigue If you found the answer then you should accept it.

Comment: Yep, I tried many times, but I had to wait 15 minutes or so to accept an answer... Done now.